# SQL statement not adding the single quotes ( ' ')

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Im writing a java program and I have a SQL statement that currently is outputting wrong:
so the code is:

```
        String sql = "SELECT Name from Users WHERE Name LIKE "+t;
```

and the Output is:

```
SELECT Name from Users WHERE Name LIKE David
```

But I need it to be with single quotes how can I add that to be like:

```
SELECT Name from Users WHERE Name LIKE 'David'
```

how can I add those quotes?

Many thanks for the help

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Use parameterized queries and you wont have to worry about it, it will also fix the huge vulnerability doing things like this manually can cause.

Comment: Don't write code like this. It opens you on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. Use prepared statements (official tutorial linked in first comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common mistake. I'm guessing you are using Statement class to create your query and executing it.

I'd like to suggest that you use prepared statements. It'll since your issue and help you with further issues.

```
PreparedStatement ps = yourconn.prepareStatement("select name from users where name like ?");

ps.setString(1,yoursearchedusername);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

This will add your quotes. Plus it will prevent from sql injection attacks in future.

Your current query will also cause issues of your actual query has ' or ? Or any other sql wild card. Prepared statement avoids all these issues and helps with performance by having the sql already compiled and stored at db layer (if enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared statement to prevent sql injections.

```
String searchedName = "cdaiga";

String sql = "SELECT Name from Users WHERE UPPER(Name) LIKE '%?%'";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, (searchedName!=null? searchedName.toUpper(): ""));

// execute the SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

// print the results if any is returned
while (rs.next()) {
   String name= rs.getString("Name");    
   System.out.println("name: " + name);
}
```

Note that a case insensitive search would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be more secure and professional  way of doing it I will work on this one.

Comment: That would ultimately produce `LIKE %'David'%`

Comment: Thanks @AlexK, it will now produce `LIKE '%DAVID%'`. I just updated the code.